# Prestashop all translatable-field display none for product page

Tags: field, admin, product, prestashop-1.6

Just new in Prestashop (1.6.0.6), I've a problem with my product page in admin. All translatable-field are to display:none (I inspect the code with chrome).

So when I want to create a new product I can't because the name field is required.

I thought that it was simple to find the .js whose do that but it isn't.

If somebody could help me, I would be happy.

Thank you for your help

---

Hi,

I make some searches and see that the function hideOtherLanguage(id) hide and show translatable-field element.

```
function hideOtherLanguage(id)
{
    console.log(id_language);
    $('.translatable-field').hide();
    $('.lang-' + id).show();    
    var id_old_language = id_language;
    id_language = id;

    if (id_old_language != id)
        changeEmployeeLanguage();

    updateCurrentText();
}
```

When I set the Id to 1 (default language), it works. It seems that when I load the page, the function is called twice and the last calling, the id value is undefined. So the show() function will not work.

If somebody could help me. Thank you.

---

In my console, I see only one error

undefined is not a function. 
under index.php / Line 1002
...
$("#product_form").validate({
...

But I find the form.tpl template and set this lines in comment but nothing change.

Comment: Open your console, maybe there are errors that need to be fixed, also did you click on the language drop down to see if you can access the language field?

Comment: I, sorry but what do you mean (open your console) ? I'm really new. Thank you.

Comment: @UnLoCo sorry but in the admin, I don't see any drop down language field. thank you.

Comment: hit F12 to open your browser console, refresh the page and tell us about any errors

Comment: @UnLoCo : I edit the post with the console log error

Comment: **Solutions below in my anser.** ...Quick **dirty** fix is to call `hideOtherLanguage(default_language)` yourself...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: According to comment on this link http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-2928 this can possibly be caused by corrupted installation file(s) - so when on clean install - try to re-download and reinstall...

## ...otherwise:

I got into a similar problem - in module admin page, when creating configuration form using PrestaShop's `HelperForm`. I will provide most probable cases and their possible solutions.

The solution for HelperForm was tested on PS 1.6.0.14

Generally there are **2 cases** when this will happen.

**First, you have to check what html you recieve.**

=> Display source code - **NOT** in developer tools/firebug/etc...!

=> I really mean the pure recieved (JavaScript **un**touched) html.

#### Check if your translatable-fields have already the inline style "`display: none`":

---

## Case 1 - fields already *have* inline style(s) for "`display: none`"

This means the template/html was already prepared this way - most probably in some TPL file I saw codes similar to these:

```
<div class="translatable-field lang-{$language.id_lang}" 
{if $language.id_lang != $id_lang_default}style="display:none"{/if}>
```

Or particularly in **`HelperForm`** template:

```
<div class="translatable-field lang-{$language.id_lang}" 
{if $language.id_lang != $defaultFormLanguage}style="display:none"{/if}>
```

Case 1 is the most easy to solve, you just have to find, where to set this default language.

### Solutions

#### HelperForm

Look where you've (or someone else) prepared the `HelperForm` object - something like:

```
$formHelper = new HelperForm();
...
```

Somewhere there will be something like `$formHelper->default_form_language = ...;`
My **wrong** first solution was to get default form language from context - which might not be set:

<del>`$this->context->controller->default_form_language; //THIS IS WRONG!`</del>

The correct way is to get the default language from configuration - something like:

```
$default_lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
$formHelper->default_form_language = $default_lang->id;
```

...this particularly solved my problem...

#### Other form-creations

If there is something else than HelperForm used for form creations, the problem is still very similar.

You have to find where in files(probably tpls) is a condition for printing `display:none` for your case - then find where is the check-against-variable set and set it correctly yourself.

---

## Case 2 - fields *don't* have inline style(s) for "`display: none`"

This means it is done after loading HTML **by JavaScript**. There are two options:

1. There is a call for `hideOtherLanguage()`, but there is wrongly set input language - that means no language will be displayed and all hidden.
   Solution for this one can be often solved by solving **Case 1** (see above). 
   In addition there can be programming error in not setting the after-used language id variable at all... then you would have to set it yourself (assign in JavaScript).
2. Some script calls some sort of .hide() on `.translatable-field` - you will have to search for it the hard way and remove/comment it out.

   ---

   #### PS: Of course you can set the language to whatever you want, it is just common to set it to default language, because it is the most easier and the most clear way how to set it.

---